# Is "school is off" correct

Tags: expressions

Is the expression "Today school is off" correct? I only know the expression "Today school is closed".

Comment: Depends.  How bad does it smell?

Comment: The school is closed. The **students** are off.

Comment: ^^ Trying out the mobile app. This should have been an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 2):

The school is closed. The **students** are off.

Edit to add: If school is over for the year/semester, (per schedule), then school is out; but I would not say "school's out" on a snow day.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: My previous claim is not valid, and as pointed out by @FumbleFinger in the comment `school is closed` indeed yields more results in Google search.

I've heard people said both, but more `school is off today` is more common. If you Google `school is off` it returns 1,880,000,000 results while `school is closed` returns only 257,000,000.It's a common expression. Just like `I took a day off from work`.

Your friendly reminder: this question may be better suited for [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: -1 - I think that's a complete misuse of Google results. If you'd even bothered to put ***quote marks*** around the search strings, you'd have got more meaningful results - ["school is off"](https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=lQ1zVf78B_L88wfdlYCQAg&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22school+is+off%22):320,000 hits; ["school is out"](https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=lQ1zVf78B_L88wfdlYCQAg&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22school+is+out%22):3,030,000; ["school is closed"](https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=KA9zVe7mJer88we0-oHQAw&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22school+is+closed%22): **6,250,000** hits.

Comment: (and I suspect the ***out*** version is significantly influenced by references to Alice Cooper's *School's out*).

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I looked things up a bit more. You're right

Answer (score 1):

One meaning of *be off*  is to be free from work, school, or some other regular occupation.(Source: Dictionary.com)

I think that a better alternative would be: *All the students got a day off from school.* or *We got a day off from school.*

Ex: Jonathan took a day off from work because he was ill.

This may help: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/be+off

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to rephrase it as: "School is off today."

You can also say, "School is closed today."

Comment: Thank you! May I know which one is more common, "Today school is off" or "Today school is close" in colloquial AmE?

Comment: I am not a native speaker, but I guess "Off" is more common.

Comment: "School is out,"   or "School is closed."

Comment: But in both the cases, you should express it in a better way. like, "School is off today" or "School is closed today."

Comment: @Hugh as I said, "I am not a native speaker." however, I think "off" also means "Not in operation or operational."

Comment: Neither is meaningfully "more common". It's *School is **closed** today* (or ***shut*** or ***not open***, etc.). The *pupils* can be ***off school today***, but the school itself almost never is. And ***close*** is grammatically incorrect.

Comment: @FumbleFingers any thoughts about https://www.facebook.com/school.almamater/posts/856149521103118

Comment: and I think @Rex got my point well.

Comment: Ngram shows *school is closed* well ahead of *School is out,*  *school is off* a small minority but perfectly understandable. Today can be pre- or post-positive.

Comment: @Mrstupid: My first thought on reading your link was that it's not written in "standard English". Then I realised it's a school in *Lahore*. Mainstream native speakers today wouldn't use the verb ***intimate*** the way it's used there (a couple of centuries ago it was used to mean *to notify formally*, but today it's invariably used with the sense of *to signify, indicate; to imply, to suggest, to hint at)*. I've no idea if the usage in the link is "standard" in IE, but it isn't standard anywhere else. The *school is off* usage isn't exactly "non-standard", but it's not all that common.

Comment: @FumbleFingers We say both "closed" and "off" here in India. so I guess you are right (:

Comment: In "standard" usage, *work/the office/factory is out today* would normally be taken to mean *the workers are **out on strike***. I remember the Alice Cooper song *School's out for summer*, which deliberately alludes to that sense, even though the *primary* meaning is *closed [for the summer holidays]*. I don't think the song title would have worked so well with ***off*** or ***closed***, but maybe they could have got away with ***down***, alluding to *Down with school!* if they were writing it today (since we've become used to usages like *the computer is **down** = not operating*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers School's out for summer, School's out forever, ***School's been blown to pieces***. 'school is out', a reference to the end of the academic year when pupils are no longer cooped up inside their classrooms. https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080713075624AAAlPav